# Can't make dotenv works with Angular5

Tags: angular

I don't understand how I'm supposed to use this package, even after reading the doc.

Here is what I tried:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare const require: any; // Typescript compiler will complain without this
declare const process: any; // Typescript compiler will complain without this
require('dotenv').config();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // This should display the content of my .env file right?
    console.log(process.env);
  }

}
```

I created a `.env` file with 3 lines, at the root of my project.
Then, I run my project with `ng serve` command.

I expected the console to show me an object with my 3 keys, but I get an empty object instead. What's happening?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello, good day, If you found the solution for this. Please post the answer. Thank you. I'm kinda experiencing the same.

Answer (score 2):

As dotenv works on the file system and is normally used for task running inside the node environment, it can't resolve the necessary .env file at runtime because your angular app is running in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

The following code :

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

is not valid for angular typescript file (.ts).

You must to create a file 'environnement.ts' in your app tree (root of your projet in your case) like this :

```
export const environment = {
   foo: true,
   bar: false
};
```

and require this file in your component with :

```
import { environment } from '../path/to/environment';
```

You can use your environment now by :

```
environment.foo 
//or 
environment.bar
```

Comment: The whole point of using dotenv for me is to NOT use `environement.ts` files. `require('dotenv').config();` seems valid for Typescript as soon as you declare the type for `require`. I have no error at build time nor run time.